# Convert Oracle SQL statement into SQL Server statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A bookings project now requires the same data extract - but from an SQL Server database - instead of Oracle. Can anyone assist converting the following into SQL Server syntax?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT o.ot_outlet_code
                             ,v.lab_site_code ot_outlet_code
                             ,v.brand
                             ,v.region
                            , bd.cd_day_date booking_date, dd.cd_day_date dining_date
                            , f.last_change_date, f.created_date
                            , f.modified_date, t15.ts_timeslot_desc
                           , t.TIME, s.session_type
                            , tbs.booking_status, f.ADDED_BY_USER
                            , bp.product, bs.booking_source
                            , f.SPECIAL_OFFER, f.SEATING_PREFERENCE
                            , f.Tables_guest_id, covers
                            , booking_occurrence, breakfast_flag
                            , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY f.Tables_guest_id ORDER BY f.last_change_date DESC, f.last_change_time DESC) rank_latest_record
                            , f.title, f.emailoptout
                            , f.MOBILE_OPT_IN, f.HIGH_CHAIR_COVERS
                            , f.GUEST_TYPE, f.Booking_ID
            FROM owbi.whs_fact_rest_booking f
                            , owbi.whs_dim_cal_date bd
                            , owbi.whs_dim_cal_date dd
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_booking_source bs
                            , owbi.whs_dim_time_of_day t
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_product bp
                            , owbi.whs_dim_15_timeslot t15
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_booking_status tbs
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_session s
                            , owbi.bat_restaurants_v v  
       WHERE f.whs_dim_outlet = v.outlet
    AND f.whs_dim_booking_date = bd.dimension_Key 
    AND f.whs_dim_dining_date = dd.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_session = s.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_booking_status = tbs.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_product = bp.dimension_Key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_booking_source = bs.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_booking_time = t.dimension_Key 
    AND f.whs_dim_dining_15_timeslot = t15.dimension_key
    AND dd.ey_year_code in ('2018')
    AND f.whs_dim_dining_date >= 20170303   
        )
WHERE rank_latest_record = 1
ORDER BY BOOKING_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your question is, or what problems you're experiencing, so I have no idea how to help you.

Comment: There is nothing in this SQL statement that would work in oracle but not in sql server as far as I know.  Did you get an error?

Comment: What is the schema of the tables, try to figure out the E-R diagrams. What is the result expected from this query

Answer (score 0):

The derived table must have an alias.  eg

```
SELECT *
FROM (
            SELECT o.ot_outlet_code
                             ,v.lab_site_code ot_outlet_code
                             ,v.brand
                             ,v.region
                            , bd.cd_day_date booking_date, dd.cd_day_date dining_date
                            , f.last_change_date, f.created_date
                            , f.modified_date, t15.ts_timeslot_desc
                           , t.TIME, s.session_type
                            , tbs.booking_status, f.ADDED_BY_USER
                            , bp.product, bs.booking_source
                            , f.SPECIAL_OFFER, f.SEATING_PREFERENCE
                            , f.Tables_guest_id, covers
                            , booking_occurrence, breakfast_flag
                            , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY f.Tables_guest_id ORDER BY f.last_change_date DESC, f.last_change_time DESC) rank_latest_record
                            , f.title, f.emailoptout
                            , f.MOBILE_OPT_IN, f.HIGH_CHAIR_COVERS
                            , f.GUEST_TYPE, f.Booking_ID
            FROM owbi.whs_fact_rest_booking f
                            , owbi.whs_dim_cal_date bd
                            , owbi.whs_dim_cal_date dd
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_booking_source bs
                            , owbi.whs_dim_time_of_day t
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_product bp
                            , owbi.whs_dim_15_timeslot t15
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_booking_status tbs
                            , owbi.whs_dim_bat_session s
                            , owbi.bat_restaurants_v v  
       WHERE f.whs_dim_outlet = v.outlet
    AND f.whs_dim_booking_date = bd.dimension_Key 
    AND f.whs_dim_dining_date = dd.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_session = s.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_booking_status = tbs.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_product = bp.dimension_Key 
    AND f.whs_dim_bat_booking_source = bs.dimension_key 
    AND f.whs_dim_booking_time = t.dimension_Key 
    AND f.whs_dim_dining_15_timeslot = t15.dimension_key
    AND dd.ey_year_code in ('2018')
    AND f.whs_dim_dining_date >= 20170303   
        ) dt
WHERE rank_latest_record = 1
ORDER BY BOOKING_DATE DESC;
```

In SQL Server it's considered poor form not use ANSI-style JOINs, although it's perfectly legal for inner joins to write them as a cross-join with the join criteria in the WHERE clause.

And it's generally better to use CTEs instead of subqueries/inline views/derived tables in the FROM clause.

Comment: What is it better to use CTEs instead of subqueries?  From a performance perspective, they should be exactly equivalent.

Comment: It's not a performance difference.  CTEs are better for readability, as the lexical order of the queries follows the logical order of the transformation pipeline.  So you can read the query from the top down, instead of from inside out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I've not found this to be true, often the execution plans will change using CTEs -- not always for the better.  (nb I've only tested this extensively on DB2).

Comment: @Hogan In virtually everything I've tested on SQL Server, a CTE is mere syntactic sugar for the same query done with sub-queries. If anything, I've found CTEs might be potentially more efficient in some edge cases, but mostly they yield the exact same plans.

Comment: @pmbAustin - I guess (like many things) this is a case where DB2 and SQL Server are *not* the same.  However, I might be exaggerating  when I say "often".  To be fair I will typically do this kind of a deep dive on very complicated queries that my clients need optimized.   These are not typical queries but complex beasts.  I think CTEs used on simple queries are just sugar as you say.